# Sequence of Smaller Sub-Problems is Known to be Which Design Approach?

Tags: programming-languages

To solve a problem, it is broken in to a sequence of smaller sub-problems, till a stage that the sub-problem can be easily solved. What is this design approach called?

Is It a, 
Top-Down approach,
Bottom-up approach,
Procedural Programming,
Dynamic programming,
Divide & Conquer

i'm Confused as the Question is asking for "Breaking into Sequence of Smaller Sub-Problems"

Procedural programming break down a programming task into Modules.
Dynamic Programming breaks problem into subproblems.
Divide & Conquer also means the same.
Top down approach is also a stepwise approach.

What would be the Exact Answer for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this design paradigm is called [divide and conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms)

Answer (score 0):

If the term **sequence** is to be taken seriously, then I would include *pipeline processing* in the description of the design approach.